# link js archive and load archive

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, hyperlink

Hi everybody i have this trouble, i have a php page that contents in the head the links to several js pages

```
<jquery.js>
<jquery-validate.js>
<functions.js>
```

the same php page have options wich one of them is showUsers.php. The showUsers page content a href that load in a div (using jquery) the page form (newUser.php). to Validate the form i use jquery validate but by any reason the query-validate is non load when the form is loaded. only works if i link the jquery-validate archive in the page form, but this solution is not worth me

anybody how can i solve this problem??

thanks for all

Comment: Show us where you're binding the validation function in your JS. It's most likely *another* delegation issue.

Comment: function SubmitUser()
{
    ValidateFormNewUser();
    
    $('#formAlta').submit( function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        
    } );
}

Comment: function ValidateFormNewUser()
{
    $('#formAlta').validate(
    {
 
         rules: {
            name: {
            required: true
            },
            lastName: {
            required: true   
            }